# How to achieve Correct Solr relevancy(Please Check Body ..)

Tags: solr, solrj, scoring, relevance, edismax

I have few fields
A,B,C,D,E,F
There's a copyField ABC

If I Search ABC:football
I want to take results from A at top in any condition
Score sort by desc,So top from A should be above

Now what it's doing is It's Calculating the Score and if Some document from having more term from B than A it's getting on Top.. Want to avoid this condition

Please Let me know if you have any Idea how can achieve this..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: try and change the similarity model?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Can't do, that might need a lot of work ..

Comment: change the default <similarity class="solr.BM25SimilarityFactory">
  <str name="k1">1.2</str>
  <str name="b">0.75</str>
</similarity>...try it by changing the b down to 0.0 you will effectively negate the impact of length-normalization, meaning two documents each matching the same single query term in the same field will always score equally...

Comment: if that would take too much of work...then search on individual fields with different boosting ...use edismax for it

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Is there any other way to boost a specific field??

Comment: `ABC:football A:football^1000` would probably give you a large enough boost to any hits in A that they come up at top?